# How to perform Ui functional automation testing using Restassured?

Tags: rest-assured, jira-rest-api

I need to automate my web application functionality using rest assured.
Means there are no endpoints to verify the functionality of login module on the homepage and I need to automate same login Page functionality using Rest Assured.
Please, anyone, tell me to know the solution of my this query.

Answer (score 0):

Rest-Assured is just a REST testing tool, you can't use it to perform UI functional testing.

You should use one of the tools dedicated to that, like Selenium.

The best way to go is to split your testing in two separate projects.

- Backend functional testing with Rest-Assured (Making REST calls).
- Frontend functional testing with Selenium (Using Selenium).